# Angular Method for populating a strongly-typed Variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and am struggling with this. Apologies if my verbiage isn't what it should be; I hope you are able to follow me.

I have some HTML with a click event that returns a row of data chosen. I want to populate a variable that is based on a model I've created. There is no issue with the click event returning the data: when I log the return I see the data chosen in the console. Nor an issue with model, which I've used elsewhere differently. My problem is that in this instance the variable is a strongly-typed array and I cannot seem to successfully assign the row data to the array.

Here is how I've defined the variable:

```
public selectedItem: thisModel[];
```

Here is the latest version of the method I've tried to assign the value of the selected row to the selectedItem variable:

```
getItemInfo(row: any[]){
      this.selectedItem =[];
      var selectedRow = row[0];
      this.selectedItem[0].Description= selectedRow.Description;
      this.selectedItem[0].StartDate= selectedRow.StartDate;
      this.selectedItem[0].EndDate= selectedRow.EndDate;
  }
```

And for good measure, here is the model, which I have imported into the component:

```
export class thisModel {

    UnitCode: number;
    Description: string;
    StartDate: Date;
    EndDate?: Date;

}
```

Unfortunately, instead of assigning the values of the selected row to the variable, the console error reads: Cannot set Description property of undefined.

As I stated previously, I've tried many different versions of this method, all giving the same result. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks to all who answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check null and undefined before set values and use push method to insert object to `selectedItem` array

```
getItemInfo(row: any[]){
      this.selectedItem =[];
      var selectedRow = row[0];
      if (selectedRow != null && selectedRow != undefined){
        this.selectedItem.push(
        { 
         Description: selectedRow.Description,
         StartDate: selectedRow.StartDate,
         EndDate: selectedRow.EndDate
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: That worked. I had to tweak it a little--got an error when writing the code because "UnitCode" was in the model and the selected row data, but not assigned in the push. Also, it barked at the ';' after selectedRow.EndDate. Thanks!